# Fullscreen Flash videos on some sites do not align with the screen in Awesome WM

Tags: awesome, fullscreen

Using the default Awesome WM settings, Flash videos from [youtube.com](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KcfGaLWzXic) are fullscreened just fine*: [image: youtube.com fullscreen screenshot]

The same type of video on [store.steampowered.com](http://store.steampowered.com/app/263340/) is both sized and positioned wrongly: [image: steampowered.com "fullscreen" screenshot]

- Cropped at the bottom.
- Top right corner about a third of a screen width away from the right edge and about half a screen height away from the top edge.

The fullscreen mode windows have virtually identical state, as shown by their `xprop` output:

```
$ diff -u youtube.xprop steam.xprop
--- youtube.xprop 2014-01-04 10:10:55.563866148 +0000
+++ steam.xprop   2014-01-04 10:11:07.943641993 +0000
@@ -7,10 +7,10 @@
                Client accepts input or input focus: True
                Initial state is Normal State.
                window id # of group leader: 0x1600001
-_NET_WM_SYNC_REQUEST_COUNTER(CARDINAL) = 23084618
+_NET_WM_SYNC_REQUEST_COUNTER(CARDINAL) = 23084626
 _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE(ATOM) = _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_NORMAL
-_NET_WM_USER_TIME(CARDINAL) = 76121035
-_NET_WM_USER_TIME_WINDOW(WINDOW): window id # 0x1603e49
+_NET_WM_USER_TIME(CARDINAL) = 76124714
+_NET_WM_USER_TIME_WINDOW(WINDOW): window id # 0x1603e51
 WM_CLIENT_LEADER(WINDOW): window id # 0x1600001
 _NET_WM_PID(CARDINAL) = 1634
 WM_LOCALE_NAME(STRING) = "en_US.UTF-8"
```

* The weird shape is because I'm using a [right tack layout](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/blob/04f535c6b71e92100bc6b85963f906ab0171e86e/.screenlayout/right-tack.sh), and I had to crop away the bits of the right part which are not actually shown on the monitor. I took the screenshot after restoring my [custom settings](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/blob/b3648c54942a7829814ec1588cdbe1349cab82ec/.config/awesome/rc.lua), but the desktop looks the same (minus the tag names) as the default.

Comment: I've had similar problems with fullscren flash and other window managers such as kwin and openbox; so this may not be specific to awesome.